# CSS Vertical Align and fancyBox

Tags: html, css, fancybox, vertical-alignment

I am working on a photo gallery(using fancyBox and PHP) for my photography page, and I can't figure out how to make the vertical align for my image gallery to be centered. 
I currently have placed mock images(from my own gallery) to figure out the layout, and I will then replace them with a PHP query to fill up the gallery with all my content automatically. I have also given each row a (temporary) different color to simply visualize the layout, as well as having a 12 division layout bar at the top for easier handling. The way I currently have my HTML and CSS code set up is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
<div class="row row-one">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/burnaby_mountain.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' src='images/photography/thumbs/burnaby_mountain.jpg'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/lions_gate.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' height="500px" src='images/photography/thumbs/lions_gate.jpg'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/bubbles.jpg'><img class='img-responsive'  src='images/photography/thumbs/bubbles.jpg'></a>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
display: table;
 }
div .row-one {
background-color: red;
display: table-row;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-lg-4 {
display: table-cell;
}
```

As you can see, I have nested the columns inside rows(I did not include the other rows' CSS code, as they're the same except for the background-color attribute, with the intention of automating the gallery later through PHP queries) and rows inside a div container called gallery. From other examples I've seen through looking up for a solution, I've seen people give the main container the display attribute of table, and rows the attribute display: table-row, and lastly the column the table-cell attribute. I have tried this, as well as many other combinations of CSS attributes and have not found a way to center the gallery.
[For a better visualization of what I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKjbT.jpg)

Thank you for your help, and excuse the lengthy question. I have been searching for a long time and it now feels like something in my code is faulty. I am fairly new to HTML/CSS and although most of my site is working as intended, this is the last bit I need to get it up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  height: 30%;
  /*   flex-direction:column; */
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-box {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/burnaby_mountain.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' src='https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/bhjivrw2chm9um9yrrmy.jpg'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/lions_gate.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' height="500px" src='https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cocker-spaniel-puppy-picture-id904219284'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/bubbles.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' src='http://cdn.bangli.uk/images/201504/article_9323_1.jpg'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/burnaby_mountain.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' src='https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/bhjivrw2chm9um9yrrmy.jpg'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/lions_gate.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' height="500px" src='https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cocker-spaniel-puppy-picture-id904219284'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a data-type='image' data-fancybox=landscape data-caption=caption href='images/photography/fres/bubbles.jpg'><img class='img-responsive' src='http://cdn.bangli.uk/images/201504/article_9323_1.jpg'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dhaval. 
It is something just like that what I am trying to do.  
However, when modifying my current code into what you have provided, replacing row-one to box and col-lg-4 to inner-box, the entire row disappears and the images are then stacked, and in some occasions the entire row just disappears. Thing to note is that I have the above code inside a container-fluid div. Could that be the issue? Any ideas? 
Will keep modifying and trying. Thanks again

Comment: Put your code in a codepen and post in comment here

Comment: I ended up solving the problem with an external class and using flexBox css attributes. I will approve your answer as my problem has been solved and your code gave me more insight as to class separation, and turned out to be fairly similar to the code you posted. Thanks again Dhaval for your help.